# How to retrieve both Text and Value from DropDownList in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in asp.net mvc which is bound using the normal binding syntax
and I can retrieve the "value" in the controller.
But I also need to display the text that is associated with this value.
I can go the hard route and query the db for this associated value.
But I wanted to know if there is an easy way to retrieve the Text as well as the Value in the controller.

Sample code I used

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("State","Pick a State")%>
```

which displays

```
"NJ", "New Jersey" etc.
```

In Controller

```
 public ActionResult  SelectState(string State)
{
  // I have value of State (NJ) ...I also need the Text for this

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that will come as part of the form submission is the value of the dropdown item.  To get both, you could change the value to be something like "value delimiter text", so something like "NJ|New Jersey".  Then you could parse it in the controller.

Comment: I thought maybe I could use JQuery to store the selected item in the dropdown and pass it down to controller. But this should suffice as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kizhakk Well, you could create a hidden field and use JQuery to populate the hidden field right before form submit.  That way you would avoid the parsing